# How to check for NaN values while using if statement in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to execute an multiple conditional If statement, If the condition passes then only further process can be executed.

I am using AND to concatenate two conditions but it gives error.

Script that i am using so far

```
if df['state']=='Delhi India' and df['contact'].notna():
   if df['status']= True:
      Print("Updated")
   else:
      print("Not Updated")
```

Any suggestion how to execute.

Using this line

```
if df['state']=='Delhi India' and df['contact'].notna():
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0):

#### We need to use bitwise operations instead.

Instead of:

```py
if df['state']=='Delhi India' and df['contact'].notna():
```

Write:

```py
if df['state']=='Delhi India' & df['contact'].notna():
```

Comment: Not working  I have also tried using df['contact'].str.len(), still not working

Comment: Try this: `if df.iloc[0]['state']=='Delhi India' and df.iloc[0]['contact'].notna():`

Comment: -  It gives the Error ""AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'notna'